# Flutter firebase error Exception has occurred. LateError (LateInitializationError: Local 'firebaseUser' has not been initialized.)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to integrate flutter and firebase. I created a flutter project and added the android and ios app and then downloaded the files to the flutter app. But when I run the project I am getting the following error

```
Exception has occurred.LateError (LateInitializationError: Local 'firebaseUser' has not been initialized.)
```

What may be the reason? These are the lines of code

```
  Future<bool> signInAnonymously() async {
if (Configurations.shared.isThisVersionTestedInAppStore ||
    Utils.isInDebugMode!) {
  late UserCredential firebaseUser;
  try {
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  } catch (e) {
    AppLogger.error(e);
  }

  return didLogInSuccessfully(withUser: firebaseUser.user);
} else {
  return false;
}}
```

main.dart file contents

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Configurations.shared.init();
  await Repository.shared.init();

  runApp(Configurations.shared.getMainAppWidget());

  runTestScripts();
}

void runTestScripts() {

  Utils.test();
  Synchronizer.test();
  Localized.test();
}
```

Comment: first of all provide your code where you getting this error and possibly you might have used `late` modifier for FirebaseUser remove that and it should work

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma, thanks for the update. I have added the lines of code in the question. Could you please have a look at?

Comment: the only thing which is causing you this error is your late keyword used for UserCredential  in `signInAnonymously()` just remove the `late` keyword and make your `UserCredential` nullable(?) and use `null check(!)` wherever neccasary

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you are attempting to use the `firebaseUser` variable without initializing it.

This is because `firebaseUser` did not get a value in the line below:

```dart
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

Since the `firebaseUser` variable can be null, you can change it from a `late` variable to a `nullable` variable like this:

Change this:

```dart
  late UserCredential firebaseUser;
```

to this:

```dart
  UserCredential? firebaseUser;
```

And update your return statement from this:

```dart
  return didLogInSuccessfully(withUser: firebaseUser.user);
```

to this:

```dart
  return didLogInSuccessfully(withUser: firebaseUser?.user);
```

This only calls the `.user` property on `firebaseUser` if the variable is not null.

Your updated code should be this:

```dart
  Future<bool> signInAnonymously() async {
    if (Configurations.shared.isThisVersionTestedInAppStore ||
      Utils.isInDebugMode!) {
      UserCredential? firebaseUser;
      try {
        firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
      } catch (e) {
        AppLogger.error(e);
      }

      return didLogInSuccessfully(withUser: firebaseUser?.user);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Victor Eronmosele, after updating the code like above the error is gone. Thank you so much.;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these lines at `main.dart` to make sure the firebase starts before the app launches.

```
Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(const ChatApp());
    }
```

Comment: yes already added that, i have added the main.dart file contents in the question.